# SSIS "While" check on iSeries field status

Tags: sql-server, ssis, package, do-while

I'm currently using a package, on MS SQL Server, that transfers data from an iSeries database to the SQLServer database. Thing is, while the operation is running, inside the iSeries server, there's a field with a status that tells us if the synch operation is working or not.

What i would like to know is, is it possible that while the package is running, it manages itself to "ping" that variable on the iSeries?

For example, from 500ms to 500ms, read the variable using a query, while the job is running. The foreach container does not allow me to check in the middle of the job, but only when it ends.

This would be like "While program = On, keep doing the job, on fail quit the job"

Hope i made myself clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**You don't know if replication is working unless you query a replicated table.**

Make a heartbeat program.  Something that updates a timestamp in a one row table.  Look at the replicated table for the correct time.  Something within one minute is working.  Update the table every 30 seconds.  A 30 second timeout on a receive data queue is accurate low overhead timer.